# Why are veth peer interfaces getting created in the current namespace instead of the target namespaces?

Tags: network-namespace, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I enter the commands below try to create a pair of network namespaces and a veth device pair to connect the namespaces.

```
$ sudo ip netns add netns_br0
$ sudo ip netns add netns_veth0
$ sudo ip link add veth0a netns netns_veth0 type veth peer veth0b netns netns_br0
```

I try to bring up one of the devices, but get an error.

```
$ sudo ip netns exec netns_veth0 ip link set veth0a up
Cannot find device "veth0a"
```

I can see that the devices are not in the intended namespaces.

```
$ sudo ip netns exec netns_br0 ip link list
62: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00

$ sudo ip netns exec netns_veth0 ip link list
63: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I can see them in my current namespace.

```
$ ip link list
...
64: veth0a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/ether 02:50:f2:0f:35:9a
65: veth0b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/ether 02:50:f2:0f:35:9b
```

I can move them into the intended namespaces.

```
$ sudo ip link set veth0a netns netns_veth0
$ sudo ip link set veth0b netns netns_br0
```

Now they're in their intended namespaces.

```
$ sudo ip netns exec netns_br0 ip link list
62: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
65: veth0b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/ether 02:50:f2:0f:35:9b

$ sudo ip netns exec netns_veth0 ip link list
63: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
64: veth0a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
link/ether 02:50:f2:0f:35:9a
```

Why doesn't the first command create them in the intended namespaces?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 Enterprise 2H12.

Comment: FWIW: On a native linux with kernel 5.19 and iproute2 versions either 5.19 or 4.20 (while OP's probably using version 5.5), OP's commands work as intended. So the remaining culprits could be kernel version, or special WSL2 interactions. I hope it's WSL2 and not WSL1 btw. You could try using `ip -n netns_veth0 link add ...` and see if this syntax behaves differently.

Comment: I tried `sudo ip -n netns_veth0 link add veth0a type veth peer veth0b netns netns_br0`. Both veth0a and veth0b got created in netns_veth0. I am using WSL2 (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2006]), I don't know which version of iproute2.

Comment: I realized that I was not running WSL2.  Apparently, checking the Windows build is not a reliable way of determining whether you're running WSL or WSL2.  A better way is to run `cat /proc/version`.  When I ran that I saw that I got `Linux version 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021`, which is WSL.

Comment: I ran `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` in command prompt. After that running `cat /proc/version` gives `Linux version 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022` and the command in the OP works.  So the solution was to force Ubuntu to use WSL 2.